# Why does assigning a table as a value to another table cause problems?

Tags: lua

How come we can't intuitively copy tables around in Lua like so:

```
a = {
  a = {},
  b = {},
}

b = {}
b = a.b
```

I've run into some weird bugs doing this. If I use a table clone function like the following, it will work fine, I just don't understand why having to use a clone function is needed/best practice in the first place.

It's hard to describe the bug I've run into when trying to do the first method, but basically, if I try to add additional key-values inside the `a.b` part of `b = a.b`, then the additional key-values don't always become what I set them to.

```
function deepCopy(object)
    local lookup_table = {}
    local function _copy(object)
        if type(object) ~= "table" then
            return object
        elseif lookup_table[object] then
            return lookup_table[object]
        end
        local new_table = {}
        lookup_table[object] = new_table
        for index, value in pairs(object) do
            new_table[_copy(index)] = _copy(value)
        end
        return setmetatable(new_table, getmetatable(object))
    end
    return _copy(object)
end
```

and then doing the following removes any bugs

```
b = deepCopy(a.b)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the bug? possible try to replicate the behavior with your `b = a.b` example

Comment: A table (as Lua value) stored in variable is just a reference to the actual table.  Copying variable just creates another reference to the same table.  To construct a copy of a table, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lua, a table is a value, and each distinct table has a distinct value. The value of a table is used to identify its contents, but the contents of a table are *not* conceptually the value of the table. That is, to access the contents of a table, you need the table's value, but the table's value is not the same thing as its contents.

The table's value can be stored in any variable. And again, that value is used to identify that table and to access that table's contents, but that is not the same thing as the value logically *being* the table's contents.

Consider the following:

```
tbl1 = { 1, 2, 3 }
tbl2 = tbl1
tbl3 = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

The value of `tbl1` and `tbl2` is the same; this means that they both refer to the same table and thus you can access the contents of that table through either variable. So `tbl1[2]` and `tbl2[2]` don't simply return 2; they both access the *same table*.

`tbl3` is *not the same table* as `tbl1`. They might have contents which are logically identical, but as far as Lua is concerned, they are different tables. Manipulating the contents of the table stored in `tbl3` will not affect anyone looking at the tables stored in `tbl1` or `tbl2`.

So, why does storing a table into a variable not copy the table's contents? Several reasons.

1. Deep copies are *expensive*. If all copies were deep, you wouldn't even be able to execute a simple `return {1, 2, 3}` without performing a copy. A pointless copy, because there are no other variables that can talk to that table (since it was created in-situ). Why waste performance? Same goes for passing a table as a parameter to a function or any number of other things.
2. Deep-copying-only prevents useful things like accessing the same table from different locations. If every table copy was deep, how could you have something as simple as a local copy of a module table? You couldn't have a table "member function" return a table internal to an object, so you can use to manipulate data in that object because that return would have to copy the table. And thus, the table object would only be mutable through direct member functions.

Deep copying is a useful tool. But it isn't the default because it shouldn't be. Most cases of copying tables don't need it, and users need a way to access a table from multiple locations.

There is no standard function or mechanism for deep copying either. The reason for that is simple: there are many ways to do a deep copy, ranging from the simple to the complex. Your simple `deepCopy` function for example breaks on a table that stores (recursively) itself:

```
me = { a = 4, other = {} }
me.other.me = me
```

That is 100% valid, and your `deepCopy` function will break on it. There are ways to implement `deepCopy` such that it will handle this, but they are complicated and expensive. Most users don't need a `deepCopy` that can handle recursive objects.

If the Lua's standard library had a deep copy function, then either it would handle every such case (and thus be expensive) or it would be a simpler one which could break on any number of corner cases (having multiple references to the same table in a table, etc).

So it's best to make any potential user of a deep copy sit down and decide exactly which cases they want to handle and which they do not.

Answer (score 4):

- Variables hold references, not entire tables.
- It's far more efficient to copy a reference than an entire table.
- A function call effectively assigns the arguments to that function's parameters, so if assignment did a full copy, it would be impossible to write a function that modifies a table.
- Usually, when we assign a table to something, we either (a) don't plan on modifying the table, or (b) explicitly intend to use at least one of the variables to modify the underlying table. See the previous point on functions. This means that doing a full copy by default would be a waste of resources.

My advice is to only copy tables when you really need to, and prefer a shallow copy unless you really need a deep copy. In fact, when I need to copy tables, I usually write a specialized copy function so I don't copy any more than I need to.